# Ignore unassigned Unicode values

Tags: java, unicode

Occasionally, there will be an unassigned Unicode point, that, when printed, shows a question mark (?). Is there a way to filter out these values?

`if(c == ?)` doesn't work of course, because the integer values are different.

[image: example]
*Here you can see some of the unassigned points*

Comment: Undefined code points aren't a common cause of question marks (or the Unicode replacement character) in text. Are you sure that you are using the correct decoder? If so, why do you have an atypical occurrence of undefined characters?

Comment: I'm using the Java standard encoder/decoder. I'm just casting the `int` values of the chars to a `char`. I believe that the font I'm using was the cause for a lot of the question marks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`java.lang.Character.isDefined(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDefined%28char%29) to filter out code points that are not assigned at all.  The version that takes a `char` as its argument cannot recognize supplementary Unicode code points, only those below U+10000.

If you also want to filter out characters that are valid but not displayable, you should additionally check [`isIdentifierIgnorable(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isIdentifierIgnorable%28int%29).

Comment: Most fonts will not contain every single printable Unicode character. You can test with a font that does have complete coverage.